# A little help with a specific script

Tags: keyboard-layout

having issues understanding the instructions on this [post](http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/1rsxkd/list_of_fixes_for_xubuntu_1310_on_the_acer_c720/chrxsjm?context=3) . I'm not sure how to apply the script. i'm on a C720 running chrubuntu. Any help would be great.

Comment: What do you exactly want? Give us more information?

Comment: I wanted to map the Keyboard shortcuts for a chromebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you do not know how to use git so forget this link http://pastebin.com/gxEcj4wu

Just download this script as `keyboard`:

```
curl http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PrPYW6SA  > keyboard
```

Then:

```
sudo bash ./keyboard
setxkbmap -query -verbose 10
```

Comment: and after that how do I set up "chromebook" as default keyboard model

Comment: "you don't need to use xbindkeys+xdotool" normally it should already work. What did happen when you executed the script? Did it run through? Did it work? Did you restart?

Comment: i changed the default keyboard in /etc/default/keyboard and ran sudo bash ./keyboard and then setxkbmap -query -verbose 10 but got a different output

Comment: Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      chromebook
layout:     us
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc104)
rules:      evdev
model:      chromebook
layout:     us

Comment: should i use http://pastebin.com/gxEcj4wu instead?

Comment: The output is ok. Did you restart and test the keys? Use this http://pastebin.com/gxEcj4wu only if you know how to apply a git patch; this is NO script. Did you push the buttons like: "search"+F1 This should be XF86Back aka BACK
"search"+F2 = XF86Forward = forward (e.g. in a browser)
"search"+F3 = XF86Reload

Comment: thanks for the help, the buttons in the browser are working, but the  brightness and the volume aren't

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  How about the others? "search"+1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 = F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10 ( this is additional F keys, native F keys working as usual)
"search"+minus = F11
"search"+equal = F12
"search"+backspace = Del
"search"+period = Ins (second key from the right shift)
"search"+left = Home
"search"+right = End
"search"+up = PgUP
"search"+down = PgDown
"search"+Alt = Capslock

Comment: What does `xmodmap -pke' output. For me it says: keycode 238 = XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp. Maybe you could try and replace `XF86MonBrightnessDown` to `XF86KbdBrightnessUp`

Comment: I get keycode 238 = XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp as well, how would i change that?

Comment: also the buttons work in browser without the addition of the search key

Comment: "This adds support for Chromebook keyboard special keys. For example, we map Search+arrows to Page Up/Down/Home/End. This is done at the browser level in Chromium OS (i.e., not at the hardware or keymap level)." from https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/master/targets/keyboard

Comment: Try `xmodmap -e "keycode 238 =XF86MonBrightnessDown"` but I don't think it will work

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the help, i guess i'm after fix at the hardware level

Comment: So you want to search for either xbindkeys or xdotool